# How Do I Write a Firefox Add-On That Turns Itself Off When in Private Mode?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I've written a working Firefox add-on. I would like this add-on to disable itself when the browser is in private mode. According to the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/EN/docs/Supporting_per-window_private_browsing I've built this wrapper around my addon:

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm");

// This plugin should not activate in a private browsing session.
if (!PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate(window)) {
  // Add-on code goes here. includes things like:
  var button = buttons.ActionButton(...);
  tabs.on('ready', ...);
  tabs.on('activate', ...);
}
```

Trouble is, I get an error, "Message: ReferenceError: window is not defined" in the line that checks "isWindowPrivate".

Is there some other way I should be accessing this property or an additional bit I need to include? This is an ActionButton add-on for Firefox 29+. Maybe the interface changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add-on SDK extensions by default opt-out of private browsing. That means you don't have to take any extra steps, the SDK simply will not allow your code to interfere with private browsing windows. And this includes `ui` components like `ActionButton`.

`window` is not defined because `main.js` runs in a windowless context. You can obtain it, if you want, but in this case you don't need it.

Comment: Does this basically mean that the "tabs.on" events just won't fire for private tabs (because they access content), but the rest of the plugin will behave normally?

Comment: Yes, all major modules take private browsing into account for you. Of course you can bypass this check, if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Determining whether or not the user is currently in private browsing mode is simple.  Just check the value of the `privateBrowsingEnabled` attribute on the `nsIPrivateBrowsingService` service.

```
var pbs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/privatebrowsing;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrivateBrowsingService);
var inPrivateBrowsingMode = pbs.privateBrowsingEnabled;

if (!inPrivateBrowsingMode) {
  /* save private information */
}
```

You can find more coding samples related to Private browsing mode from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Supporting_private_browsing_mode)

Comment: Although you should check the window if it's in private, or tab if its in private. I think this just checks if theres any instance of private browsing anywhere, is my estimation correct akhil?

Comment: This is wrong, private browsing is no longer a global flag in Firefox - each browser window can be using private browsing independently. In fact, `nsIPrivateBrowsingService` interface doesn't even exist any more.

Comment: Looks like the docs say it's going to be removed in 21, which must by why I got a reference error accessing "@mozilla.org/privatebrowsing;1".

Answer (score 0):

There is a quirk to importing modules in the Add-on SDK, you must import the symbols explicitly:

```
var {PrivateBrowsingUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm");
```

Other than that your code seems correct